# How to parse the day of the Date object as an integer?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Date object, and I want to get the day number, and add to it another integer. The point is that I have a code like the one below, but it concatenates them as a string, doesn't evaluate them as an integer.

```
var d = inputDate.getDate();
var num = 4;
var temp = parseInt(d)+num;
```

Assuming, `getDate` returns `25` for the *25th* day, and if I add `4`, the result of temp becomes `254`, instead of `29`. Any ideas?

**EDIT :**

In HTML, I have something like this, a datepicker.

```
<form action="#" method="get">
       <input id="dpicker" type="date">
</form>
```

Then in JS, I have something like this:

```
$(document).on("pagechange", function(event, ui) {
    if ($.mobile.activePage[0].id == "ovulInfoPicker") {
        $('input[type="date"]').change(function() {
            inputDate = new Date(this.value);
        });
    }
});
```

Please also note, I'm using jQuery 1.9.1, and jQuery Mobile 1.3.1, and creating a small mobile app.

**EDIT 2:**

The value that I want to add to my day, is from a select/option element.

```
        <p>
            How many days did your menstrual cycle last?
            <select id="menstrualCycle" onclick="changeFunc('menstrualCycle')">
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
            </select>
        </p>

function changeFunc(select) {
    var selectBox = document.getElementById(select);
    var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;

    if (select == 'monthCycle') {
        monthDays = selectedValue;
        console.log("Month value is: " + monthDays);
    } else if (select == 'menstrualCycle') {
        menstrualDays = selectedValue;
        console.log("Menstrual value is: " + menstrualDays);
    } else if (select == 'lutealPhase') {
        lutealValue = selectedValue;
        console.log("Luteal value is: " + lutealValue);
    }
}


var d = inputDate.getDate();
var temp = d+menstrualDays; // returns 254, for 25th day, and 4 as a value for menstrualDays
```

Comment: How are you getting `inputDate`?  I cannot replicate the problem using `new Date();`  http://jsfiddle.net/gunderjt/bA3La/1/

Comment: Please show how you are getting `inputDate`

Comment: Works for me here.http://jsfiddle.net/ya6Vt/1/

Comment: Did a final edit, I forgot to mention that the number of days I'm getting from a select/option element.

Comment: It's because the value you get from the options is a string. So parse it as well!

Comment: @opp Parsing both of them worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On changing the `select` the value will update.
**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VNpst/4/)**

```
<p>How many days did your menstrual cycle last?
    <select onChange="changeFunc()" id="menstrualCycle">
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
    </select>
</p>

<input type="text" id="result" value="3">
```

```
    function changeFunc() {
    var myselect = document.getElementById("menstrualCycle");
    console.log(myselect.options[myselect.selectedIndex].value);

    var day = new Date();
    var z=$(dpicker).val().split("-");

    //var dt = new Date()
    if (myselect == 'monthCycle') {
        monthDays = selectedValue;
        //alert("Month value is: " + monthDays);
    } else if (myselect == 'menstrualCycle') {
        menstrualDays = selectedValue;
        //alert("Menstrual value is: " + menstrualDays);
    } else if (myselect == 'lutealPhase') {
        lutealValue = selectedValue;
        //alert("Luteal value is: " + lutealValue);
    }

    var number = myselect.options[myselect.selectedIndex].value
    var elem = document.getElementById("result");
    elem.value = parseInt(z[2]) + parseInt(number);   
}
```

Comment: I thought OP wanted the day of the **month**, not the day of the **week**

Comment: I did something like this: var dd = inputDate.getDate().getDay(); but it shows an error message: Object 25 has no method "getDay", please note that I selected 25th day of the month.

Comment: @blgt Yes, I need the day in the month.

Comment: @Austin sorry for me, I did a new edit. I forgot to mention that the number of days I'm getting from a select/option element. And your example doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: Yup I am toying around with it right now. rest assured, I shall solve this case!! :D

Comment: @Austin parsing both the date and the value from option works.

Comment: Question, what is role of having a datepicker? Wouldn't you just want today's date?

Comment: @Austin no, the user selects a specific date, where later I do somethings with it.

Comment: @ett Alright I got the compile kink sorted out, so what you want from us is a `var` holding datepicker's day + the value selected? Do we need to do any of that `if` logic or just get you the value stated above?

Answer (score 0):

Like I mentioned in the comment, you have to parse the value you get from the options element.

Just for the record: The value is always a string as per definition (http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-1-20000929/idl-definitions.html). Here are all the values you get back from `<option>`

```
interface HTMLOptionElement : HTMLElement {
    readonly attribute HTMLFormElement  form;
             attribute boolean          defaultSelected;
    readonly attribute DOMString        text;
    readonly attribute long             index;
             attribute boolean          disabled;
             attribute DOMString        label;
             attribute boolean          selected;
             attribute DOMString        value;
  };
```